# tkinter listbox display problems

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox

I've been trying to get a listbox to work, however, I've had no success at all. The box appears, and the data too... but all together. I have a list that looks something like this:

```
lst=["item1","\n","item2","\n","item3","\n"]
```

my listbox code looks somewhat like this:

```
s=""
for x in lst:
    s+=str(x)

itemlist=Listbox(window)
itemlist.insert(0,s)
itemlist.place(x=100,y=120)
```

the problem is, when I run it, the listbox displays like a joinlist, something like this:

```
item1item2item3
```

is there a way to get the listbox to actually work in displaying each item like this:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you asked it to. You explicitly combined all of your strings into one big string and inserted that one big string. If that's not what you want, why did you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was trying to get the "for" to get the "\n" and display it, didn't work tho xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm), you have to `insert` each item separately, rather than `insert`ing one large string. Using `append` to build a `list` works in a similar way.

```
lst=["item1","item2","item3"]

itemlist=Listbox(window)
for item in lst:
    itemlist.insert(END,item)
itemlist.place(x=100,y=120)
```

Comment: You, my friend, are absolutely right! (BTW I think this is like the fifth time you have helped me, really, Thanks)

Comment: I guess `itemlist.insert(END,*lst)` should insert all items at once.